# Does check day and hour need to check timezone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, timezone, timezone-offset

My code to check day and hour like this :

```
function checkDay() {
  var day = new Date();
  if (day.getDay() >= 1 && day.getDay() <= 5 && day.getHours() >= 9 && day.getHours() < 17) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

I want every Monday to Friday 9 to 17, it's true. Apart from that, it is false

I had test it and it works. Is it necessary to check Timezone?

My position at Indonesia (GMT + 7)

If I implement timezone, it like this :

```
function checkDay() {
  const offsetHours = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
  const day = new Date();

  day.setHours(day.getHours() + offsetHours);

  return day.getDay() >= 1 && day.getDay() <= 5 && day.getHours() >= 2 && day.getHours() < 10;
}
```

Is it necessary to check Timezone like that?

Comment: If you want to, yes. You can serve the datetime from your server if you want expats to understand what 9-17 is in your place

Comment: As an aside, your first version would be simpler using the same return statement as your second - there's no need for the `if (condition) { return true; } else { return false; }`

Comment: @mplungjan Actually I had try my first code and it works without timezone. I just for make sure this

Comment: @JonSkeet Okay. Is it necessary to check Timezone like that?

Comment: @positivethinking: It was an aside; separate from the main point of the question (which is about time zones). My point is that the nature of the return statement in the second piece of code is simpler than the if statement in the first piece of code. That's entirely independent of the time zone part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first piece of code is already correct because `getHours` and `getDay` already operate in the local time zone. As per the [MDN Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Note: It's important to keep in mind that while the time value at the heart of a Date object is UTC, the basic methods to fetch the date and time or its components all work in the local (i.e. host system) time zone and offset.

Likewise the ECMAScript specifications (e.g. [ECMA 262, 2015 edition](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/ECMA-262.pdf)) describe the behaviour as going via the `LocalTime` abstract operation:

> The abstract operation LocalTime with argument t converts t from UTC to local time

Comment: Okay. So I must to using timezone like my second script on the question above

Comment: @positivethinking: No, exactly the opposite - your first piece of code already works, assuming you want the value in the local time zone. Will edit to clarify.

Comment: Means my first script is correct and doesn't need modification. Thanks

Comment: I had select first script as best option to implement my case. But for example If I select second script, that also doesn't matter right?

Comment: @positivethinking: I would *expect* it to give the wrong answer, as you'd be performing a comparison against a different moment in time. They can't both be right. (Also, your code assumes that every time zone offset is a whole number of hours.)

Comment: Okay. So My first script is the best solution